# javascript - load link inside modal from external source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to create a dynamic website using modals that load some code from other source, in this case I want my users to select a product from the modal view using a link and then a confirm button something like this

Main page -> button -> loads modal (modal source is external page("prods.php"))-> selects product inside modal using button -> modal now shows ("prod_detail.php") -> confirm -> data returned to main page

this is my actual code of the modal loading external source, but I cant get it to load the new prod_detail, because it opens in the main window

```js
//called when user clicks login
function login() {
    $("#main-username").val($("#modal-username").val());
    $("#main-result").val($("#modal-result").val());
    $("#myModal").modal("hide");
}

//called when the modal is closed, logs values grabbed from the modal in login()
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function() {
    console.log('username : '+$("#main-username").val());
    console.log('result : '+$("#main-result").val());
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- button to trigger modal -->
<a href="prods.php" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">remote modal</a>

<!-- hidden fields to store modal result in -->
<input type="text" id="main-username">
<input type="text" id="main-result">

<!-- modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal test</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="login();">Login</button>
  </div>
</div>​


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you just trying to load the HTML from a source into your modal? Could an iFrame do the job?

Comment: Where is the code to load prod_detail.php?

Comment: @webdeb  I am using modal because I need to get data back from the page

Comment: You can use **window.parent**

Comment: I wrote an example how you could do it with an iframe..

Answer (score 0):

Your main window:

```
<!-- hidden fields to store modal result in -->
<input type="text" id="main-username">
<input type="text" id="main-result">

<script>
window.setData = function(data) {
  console.log('data from iframe', data);
} 
</script>

<!-- modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <iframe src="/prods.php"></iframe>
</div>​
```

... prods.php

```
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal test</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.parent.setData("HI from iframe")">Say Hi to Main Window</button>
  </div>
```